# How to filter IEnumerable with <select> for second <select>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dictionary, ienumerable

In my angular script i declare the following by pulling from my viewmodel provided by my ASP.net controller:

```
$scope.controlleractions = @Html.Raw(Json.JsonCamelCase(Model.ControllerActions));
```

resulting in the following data:

```
[{"$id":"1",
"controller":"Resource",
"actions":["Image","File"]},

{"$id":"2",
"controller":"Home",
"actions":["Index","NotAuthorized"]},

{"$id":"3",
"controller":"Email",
"actions":["Index","Details","Adress"]},

{"$id":"4",
"controller":"Account",
"actions":["Index","Login","Logout","Create"]},

{"$id":"5",
"controller":"Archive",
"actions":["Page1","Page2","Page3","Search"]}]
```

I want to be able to select a controller by a select element and then select an action from the actions array with a second select element, but i can't seem to work it out. Anybody an idea?

both outputs in the ng-models are preferred to be in string

this is how far i got:

```
<!-- selecting a controller works fine -->
<select ng-model="selectedController">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="controlleraction in controlleractions">{{controlleraction.controller}}</option>
</select>

<!-- selecting an action from actions that match the selected controller dosn't work -->
<select ng-model="selectedAction">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="action in controlleractions.actions | filter : selectedController">{{action}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use `filter` here, but simply bind your `ng-repeat` on `selectedController` instead :

```
 <option ng-repeat="action in selectedController.actions">{{action}}</option>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it dosn't work. selectedController is a string and not an object that holds a list of actions.

Comment: i could have changed the value in the first <select> to be a object with a list (controlleraction) but then the output from ng-model is not a string anymore which i prefer to mutate other data back to my ASP.net controller

Comment: Then I think you should use a third variable corresponding to the actual controller in order to have its actions.